# Rails fresh_when should include current user id in etag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, etag, http-caching, ruby-on-rails-6

I see many examples like this:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  fresh_when(@article)
end
```

However the page also contains information (like top navigation) about the logged in user. A user  can:

- log in as user A
- visit the article
- log out
- log in as user B
- visit the article again

... Oops the user will see data about user A, instead of user B, because the article was not modified.

How can I include the current user id in the hash (etag)? Or, are there any other solutions to avoid the issue described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can add the current_user id to the etag in all of your controllers.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  etag { current_user.try :id }
end
```

This way, you can solve the problem with the logged-in user who might get different content than a non-logged-in user.